# Change "Proceed To Checkout" Button Location Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a new page in between the cart and checkout pages on woocommerce shop.

How can i change the "proceed to checkout" url on the standard cart page to link to my new page called "extras"

This new extras page will offer the customer an extra product they can add to their cart and then proceed back to the checkout page as normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code will change the URL of the **Proceed to Checkout**.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);

add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'change_url_to_checkout', 20);

function change_url_to_checkout(){
        $extra_url = 'put_your_extra_page_url_here';
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $extra_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php   
}
```

**WooCommerce** add that url with action and does not provide `filter` to change the URL. So we need to remove **action** and again need to `add_action` to achieve.